# exploring ios diractory using using phonegap

Tags: ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating app using jquery Mobile and Phonegap 1.6.0, and I want to upload files to server, is there any way to explore/browse the IOS directories to select file and upload that file using Phonegap API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this with a 10 second search of the docs:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File Is this what you want?

Comment: i know about this. but the prob is that how can i explore ios directory. this link only shows way to upload. but how to choose file?

Comment: @muneebShabbir It definitely shows more than that...what about the `DirectoryReader` object...?

Comment: i think `DirectoryReader` will starts listing down from Root directory. but the problem is that, if myfile.txt is at root->dir1->dir2->myfile.txt how user can explore these directories easily?

Comment: And do i have to take input from user as a plain text of filename?

Comment: Your question doesnt mention that you want this as a user interface element.  That is a different question.  You will need to write the ui yourself, using the above mentioned functions for a backend.  Dont ask how because that question is too broad.

Comment: hmm.. thanks, <input type="file"> is not supported is there any other way to browse directory?